# InfoPath getting too much time to load data from list

Tags: infopath

I have created on InfoPath in which I have several data connections. One list have almost one thousands list items, I am fetching items by using data connections.

1. I have checked on "Automatically retrieve data when form is opened"[image]

It was working fine when I preview the form but when I deployed, it has taken almost 3 min to load data and fill all dropdown fields.

2. Then I split data connections to multiple data connections and used "Query for Data" action on first dropdown field(for this data connection, I have checked Automatically retrieve data when form load) to load data for second dropdown field and another "Query for Data" on second dropdown to fill third dropdown and so on.. but then after third dropdown I have some textbox to filled the data, I have queried rest of all data connections to third dropdown.

Now, it is taking too much time to load data after I select the value from third dropdown list.

What should be design approach here? How can I minimize loading time? I don't have code behind for this form.

Comment: Oh 2 up votes and 18 Views .. still no solution? :(